# Using \crefformat with cleveref causes spurious chktex warnings

Tags: cleveref, syntax, syntax-checker, chktex

Cleveref has a useful feature in \crefformat where an equation can be referred to, for instance, an inequality. This adds an extra square-bracket argument to the \label command. For example:

```
\crefformat{inequality}{inequality~(#2#1#3)}

\begin{equation}
    S \leq 2.
    \label[inequality]{eqn:bell}
\end{equation}
```

However, when using chktex for syntax validation there are two spurious syntax warnings. First, it points to the closing square bracket on the \label line saying

> Solo `]' found.

and secondly, on the final line of the document it says

> Number of `[' doesn’t match the number of ']'.

I do not simply want to turn these warnings off as I believe there is some underlying explanation for these warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called something like `mychktexrc` somewhere, containing

```
WipeArg
{
    \label:[]{} \ref:{} \eqref:{} \vref:{} \pageref:{} \index:[]{}
    \cite:[][]{} \nocite:{}
    \input:{} \verbatiminput:[]{} \listinginput:[]{}{}
    \verbatimtabinput:[]{} \include:{} \includeonly:{}
    \bibitem:[]{}
    \cline:{} \cmidrule:[](){}
    \href:{}{}
    # Cleveref -- there are many others that could be here as well...
    \cref:*{} \cpageref:*{} \crefrange:*{}{} \cpagerefrange:*{}{}
    \Cref:*{} \Cpageref:*{} \Crefrange:*{}{} \Cpagerefrange:*{}{}
    # natbib
    \citet:*[][]{} \citep:*[][]{} \citealt:*{} \citealp:*[]{} \citeauthor:*{}
    \Citet:*[][]{} \Citep:*[][]{} \Citealt:*{} \Citealp:*[]{} \Citeauthor:{}
    \citetext:{} \citeyear:*{} \citeyearpar:{}
    # tipa which uses "
    \textipa:{}
}
```

which is the same entry as in the default `chktexrc` file, but with `\label` marked to accept an optional argument.

Then running

```
chktex -l mychktexrc filename
```

you shouldn't get any error message.

The argument for the `-l` command line option should have the path for the created file.

Comment: I created a new file ´~/.chktexrc´ with the contents specified. In order to get the vim syntastic plugin to use this rc file I added the following to my .vimrc: `let g:syntastic_tex_chktex_args = ("-l \"".$HOME."\\.chktexrc\"")`